# Pygame laggy on a MacBook Pro

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a video game with Pygame on my MBP 2013 (i5, 4go RAM, intel iris 1536mo) and any sample i can find on the web is insanely laggy.
However if I launch those games with an older mac (2011) - but with a dedicated graphic card (??) - I can play games without FPS issues

Here is one of the sample (from http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?lang=en&chapter=example_code_platformer)

I tried to `change pygame.display.flip()` with `pygame.display.update()` without success, and `clock.tick(30)` with `pygame.timer.wait()` with random results...

Any idea that could solve my problem ?

```
"""
Sample Python/Pygame Programs
Simpson College Computer Science
http://programarcadegames.com/
http://simpson.edu/computer-science/

From:
http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/f.php?file=platform_scroller.py

Explanation video: http://youtu.be/QplXBw_NK5Y

Part of a series:
http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/f.php?file=move_with_walls_example.py
http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/f.php?file=maze_runner.py
http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/f.php?file=platform_jumper.py
http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/f.php?file=platform_scroller.py
http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/f.php?file=platform_moving.py
http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/sprite_sheets/

"""

import pygame
import time

# Global constants

# Colors
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
BLUE     = (   0,   0, 255)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)
GREEN    = (   0, 255,   0)

# Screen dimensions
SCREEN_WIDTH  = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the bar at the bottom that the player controls.
    """

    # -- Attributes
    # Set speed vector of player
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0

    # List of sprites we can bump against
    level = None

    # -- Methods
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor function """

        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        width = 40
        height = 60
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        # Set a referance to the image rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        """ Move the player. """
        # Gravity
        self.calc_grav()

        # Move left/right
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        # See if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right,
            # set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        # Move up/down
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        # Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:

            # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            elif self.change_y < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

            # Stop our vertical movement
            self.change_y = 0

    def calc_grav(self):
        """ Calculate effect of gravity. """
        if self.change_y == 0:
            self.change_y = 1
        else:
            self.change_y += .35

        # See if we are on the ground.
        if self.rect.y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.change_y >= 0:
            self.change_y = 0
            self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height

    def jump(self):
        """ Called when user hits 'jump' button. """

        # move down a bit and see if there is a platform below us.
        # Move down 2 pixels because it doesn't work well if we only move down 1
        # when working with a platform moving down.
        self.rect.y += 2
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        self.rect.y -= 2

        # If it is ok to jump, set our speed upwards
        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.change_y = -10

    # Player-controlled movement:
    def go_left(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the left arrow. """
        self.change_x = -6

    def go_right(self):
        """ Called when the user hits the right arrow. """
        self.change_x = 6

    def stop(self):
        """ Called when the user lets off the keyboard. """
        self.change_x = 0

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ Platform the user can jump on """

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        """ Platform constructor. Assumes constructed with user passing in
            an array of 5 numbers like what's defined at the top of this code.
            """
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(GREEN)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Level():
    """ This is a generic super-class used to define a level.
        Create a child class for each level with level-specific
        info. """

    # Lists of sprites used in all levels. Add or remove
    # lists as needed for your game.
    platform_list = None
    enemy_list = None

    # How far this world has been scrolled left/right
    world_shift = 0

    def __init__(self, player):
        """ Constructor. Pass in a handle to player. Needed for when moving
            platforms collide with the player. """
        self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = player

    # Update everythign on this level
    def update(self):
        """ Update everything in this level."""
        self.platform_list.update()
        self.enemy_list.update()

    def draw(self, screen):
        """ Draw everything on this level. """

        # Draw the background
        screen.fill(BLUE)

        # Draw all the sprite lists that we have
        self.platform_list.draw(screen)
        self.enemy_list.draw(screen)

    def shift_world(self, shift_x):
        """ When the user moves left/right and we need to scroll everything: """

        # Keep track of the shift amount
        self.world_shift += shift_x

        # Go through all the sprite lists and shift
        for platform in self.platform_list:
            platform.rect.x += shift_x

        for enemy in self.enemy_list:
            enemy.rect.x += shift_x

# Create platforms for the level
class Level_01(Level):
    """ Definition for level 1. """

    def __init__(self, player):
        """ Create level 1. """

        # Call the parent constructor
        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1000

        # Array with width, height, x, and y of platform
        level = [[210, 70, 500, 500],
                 [210, 70, 800, 400],
                 [210, 70, 1000, 500],
                 [210, 70, 1120, 280],
                 ]


        # Go through the array above and add platforms
        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)

# Create platforms for the level
class Level_02(Level):
    """ Definition for level 2. """

    def __init__(self, player):
        """ Create level 1. """

        # Call the parent constructor
        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1000

        # Array with type of platform, and x, y location of the platform.
        level = [[210, 30, 450, 570],
                 [210, 30, 850, 420],
                 [210, 30, 1000, 520],
                 [210, 30, 1120, 280],
                 ]


        # Go through the array above and add platforms
        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)

def main():
    """ Main Program """
    pygame.init()

    # Set the height and width of the screen
    size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    pygame.display.set_caption("Side-scrolling Platformer")

    # Create the player
    player = Player()

    # Create all the levels
    level_list = []
    level_list.append(Level_01(player))
    level_list.append(Level_02(player))

    # Set the current level
    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level

    player.rect.x = 340
    player.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.rect.height
    active_sprite_list.add(player)

    #Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False

    # Used to manage how fast the screen updates
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    tick = 0
    current_milli_time = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    mtime = current_milli_time()
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
                done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.go_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.go_right()
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.jump()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.change_x < 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.change_x > 0:
                    player.stop()

        # Update the player.
        active_sprite_list.update()

        # Update items in the level
        current_level.update()

        # If the player gets near the right side, shift the world left (-x)
        if player.rect.right >= 500:
            diff = player.rect.right - 500
            player.rect.right = 500
            current_level.shift_world(-diff)

        # If the player gets near the left side, shift the world right (+x)
        if player.rect.left <= 120:
            diff = 120 - player.rect.left
            player.rect.left = 120
            current_level.shift_world(diff)

        # If the player gets to the end of the level, go to the next level
        current_position = player.rect.x + current_level.world_shift
        if current_position < current_level.level_limit:
            player.rect.x = 120
            if current_level_no < len(level_list)-1:
                current_level_no += 1
                current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
                player.level = current_level

        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT
        current_level.draw(screen)
        active_sprite_list.draw(screen)

        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

        if tick %30 == 0:
            print (current_milli_time() - mtime)
            mtime = current_milli_time()
        tick+=1
        # Limit to 30 frames per second
        clock.tick(30)

        # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
        pygame.display.flip()

    # Be IDLE friendly. If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
    # on exit.
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Game performance relies on the factors:

```
1. CPU usage required for the game
2. Graphics card and their drivers
3. Random Access Memory aka RAM
```

Because Pygame programs aren't anything industrial, there shouldn't be too much CPU usage from your game. As for the Graphics card, you should be all set, I mean it's a MacBook Pro. You've probably got Intel HD Graphics. Lastly your RAM, is probably the source of lagging.

RAM stores the used data for the current user session. If you've only got 2 GB of memory, and you have thousands of assets and variables in your game, you're sure to be using a good amount of memory. You can either:

```
1. Limit other processes or programs.
2. Compress game assets and variables.
3. Upgrade the amount of RAM.
```

Only resort to the last one if you're desperate.

Comment: CPU is super high (70-80%) and ram is not a problem since even a little sample game freezes like crazy...

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you. Do you have an ideas yourself?

Comment: No, I'm on this issue for 4 days now, I still don't know what is going on... Iris Graphics seems lazy, CPU and RAM are ok... I don't know much about SDL and stuff (bad install or something ... ?)